# Measure time taken during Fortran program

Tags: fortran, timing

I have recently started learning Fortran for the fun of it, and I want to know if there is any simple way to display the time taken to execute my code. It is just simple loop that counts to a million, and I want to see how long it takes to do that.

If it helps, here is the code I'm using:

```
program count
    implicit none
    integer :: i

    do i=0,1000000
        print*,i
    end do
end program count
```

I am on Linux using gFortran as my compiler. I am using Geany as a text editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Fortran 90 or later, use the SYSTEM_CLOCK intrinsic subroutine:

```
call system_clock(beginning, rate)
result = do_computation()
call system_clock(end)
print *, "elapsed time: ", real(end - beginning) / real(rate)
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to `call cpu_time(timeVariable)`.

Sample:

```
program ElapsedTime
  implicit none

  integer :: i
  real :: startTime, stopTime

  call cpu_time(startTime)

  do i = 1, 1000000000
     if(mod(i,10000000)==0)then
        print *,"iter: ", i
     endif
  end do

  call cpu_time(stopTime)
  
  write(*, '(A, F8.6)') 'Elapsed time, s : ',  (stopTime - startTime)

end program
```